# Is Windows 8 fully compatible with latest Macbook Air 13"?

Tags: macbook-pro, compatibility, windows

I am planning the next laptop and I really like the Macbook Air 13" hardware, looks, and weight. On the other hand, for certain reasons I need Windows, so in case I stick with buying MBA13" I am going to remove OSX and install W8 instead.

One of my biggest concerns here is whether W8 is *fully* compatible with MBA. I really would like *all* features work correctly - webcam, brightness/volume buttons, mic, cooling fan control, close/open lid, etc.

Comment: This would be better if you enumerated each and every item that "full compatibility" means. I've edited out the chatty discussion side of "share any experience" since we like to have discussions in the [chat] rooms and concrete, answerable questions on the main site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is fully compatible. But since Windows 8 is heavily dependent on multi touch gestures, and the trackpad driver of a mac isn't the best... well its not recommended. I use bootcamp with Windows 8, but since Apple are the one who need to upgrade and update both the drivers and the bootcamp for almost every major Windows realise the experince might not be as good as a "native" pc, by this I mean you can get third party drivers, as I did, and it does work, but if you buy a Mac for the hardware I suggest you look at other alternatives as it doesn't function as well with Windows as it does with Mac!

You can get look alikes that perform better on Windows! I can say personally I buy Macs because of MAC OS X the hardware is only a plus, if I wasnt going to use Mac software i would probably look in to the [Samsung Series 9](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/series-9-notebooks). However the options are many, but if your main use is to buy a Mac in order to use Windows, I personally recommend you to look elsewhere, and if you are planning on partitioning your drive and only install Windows, well honestly you can get better hardware for less money. although probably uglier! (some exceptions)

-this is from an avid mac and pc user-

*If you have any questions, concerns, or need any assistance in future, please don't hesitate to reply to me. I'll be happy to assist you further.*

**Update 1:**

Well except for the core i7 which can probably be configured in store, you can get most ultrabooks cheaper and update the ram and ssd yourself, I think my favorite pc-ultrabook (samsung series 9) is easy to upgrade yourself!
here are some links however

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2407200,00.asp

http://www.theverge.com/products/aspire-s7-13-3-inch/5713

http://www.theverge.com/2012/7/5/3135319/asus-zenbook-prime-ux31a-review

http://www.engadget.com/2011/11/13/lenovo-ideapad-u300s-review/

still, go in to a store and try and feel them out, focus on the trackpad! Especially in windows 8

Comment: If you know where i can get a 13" laptop of 1.35 kg with Core i7, 8GB RAM and 512GB SSD cheaper than MBA, you are highly welcome to share this knowledge :)

Comment: well exept for the core i7 witch can probably be configured in store, you can get most ultrabooks cheaper and update the ram and ssd yourself for much cheaper!
here are some links however

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what others experiences are with trackpad etc but mine has been that it is perfectly usable. Gestures etc all work for the most part. Ymmv. With bootcamp and/or Parallels.

Answer (score 0):

With the last bootcamp release Windows 8 is fully compatible with MBA 13 (Mid 2011 or newer)

For more information check this link:

[Boot Camp: Frequently asked questions about installing Windows 8](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5628)

Answer (score 0):

The latest MacBook Air 13 is fully compatible with Windows 8. You can install [Trackpad++](http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/) to enable all the multitouch gestures.

The only thing missing would be fast booting using EFI, i.e. your Windows 8 would boot in 45 seconds to one minute instead of 15 seconds, which is possible these days with Windows 8.

Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: I dont think this is true on an SSD. My 2010 Macbook pro boots to the Windows 7 desktop in 15 seconds after I upgraded the hard disk to an SSD. I am sure a 2013 Macbook air will equal or better that.